# Impact on CircuitLab schematic integration of moving from Imgur to a different image hosting service

Tags: discussion, status-review, circuitlab

[Stack Exchange’s image hosting arrangement with Imgur is ending - advance notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395024/1203959) on the main meta site notes that the hosting contract with Imgur comes to an end this upcoming April 2024, requiring a change to the image hosting service.

At the moment, posts which have made use of the CircuitLab schematic editor have text of the following form in the post, where the schematic is referenced by the *png image file* on Imgur:

```
<!-- Begin schematic: In order to preserve an editable schematic, please
     don't edit this section directly.
     Click the "edit" link below the image in the preview instead. -->

![schematic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wtRde.png)

<!-- End schematic -->
```

Searching on Electrical Engineering Meta for how the CircuitLab schematic editor integration works found the [answer](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9895/101063) which contains:

> My guess is that CircuitLab stores the editable schematics in a database, and the URL of the png image file is used as a key to recover the schematic.

When the image hosting service is changed, what needs to be done to preserve the CircuitLab schematic editor integration on posts before and after the change of image hosting provider?

Ideally users would still be able to edit schematics made before the change of image hosting provider.

I'm asking this new question in the Electrical Engineering Meta, rather commenting on the above main meta question, as not sure exactly:

1. How the CircuitLab schematic editor integration is implemented
2. If both the Stack Exchange and CircuitLab ends need to change or not

Comment: Good point, I'll have someone look at it.